# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH' has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error, turtle-graphics

cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

Comment: cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000) cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jeru Luke Drop CV_

Comment: @toyotaSupra removed my comment

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000) 
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
```

to:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
```